# How to deserialize a nested Document into a specific class object?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm new to MongoDb and I'm attempting to serialize an array of Documents that are nested within a parent document into a specific class object.

**My Document object looks like this:**

```
Project
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("589da20997b2ae4608c99173"),
    // ... additional fields
    "Products" : [ 
        { 
            "_id" : ObjectId("56971340f3a4990d2c199853"),
            "ProductId" : null,
            "Name" : null,
            "Description" : null,
            // ... quite a few more properties
            "Properties" : null 
        }
    ],
    "CreatorUserId" : LUUID("af955555-5555-5555-5555-f1fc4bb7cfae")
}
```

So basically its a Document named `Project` that contains a nested array of `Product` Documents.

**Here are what the current classes look like:**

```
public class Project : BaseClasses {
    public ObjectId ParentCreatorUserIdProject { get; set; }  
    // ... additional Fields 
    public IEnumerable<IProjectItem> ProjectItems { get; set; } 
    //public IEnumerable<IProductDetails> Products { get; set; }
}

[DataContract][Serializable]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements][MongoCollection("products")]
public class Product {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; 
    // .. a bunch of Fields
}
```

### Current Behavior

Currently the `Project` document comes back with a serialized array of `Product`.

### Desired Behavior

I would like the Document to come back with a serialized array of  `ProjectItems`. The `ProjectItems` class is straightforward:

```
[Serializable]
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class ProjectItem {
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; 
    // .. a handful of Fields
}
```

### My Attempt

I have attempted to create a mapping using `BsonClassMap` however, I just don't know enough about this class type despite having read the [entire document on mapping](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.2/reference/bson/mapping/). I should note that I have defined this class map with the previous developers other mappings and am sure (Unit Tests) that they execute.

```
  BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProjectItem>(cm => {
      cm.AutoMap();
      cm.SetDiscriminator("ProjectItem");
      cm.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
  });
```

Unfortunately the document still gets serialized into an array of `Product`.

### My Question

How can I serialize this nested array of Products into an array of ProjectItem classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer turns out to be pretty simple... Whatever type you stored it as is what you want to set as your discriminator.

```
  BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProjectItem>(cm => {
      cm.AutoMap();
      cm.SetDiscriminator("Product"); // <--- it was stored as a Product
      cm.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
  });
```

Let's see another example for my fellow MongoDb newbies... if your `Product` was originally stored as a `ProductDetails` your object would have an `_t` in the database. The `_t` tells MongoDb what type it was stored as.

So your object could look like this:

```
"Products" : [ 
    { 
         "_t" : "ProductDetails",
         "_id" : ObjectId("56971340f3a4990d2c199853"),
         "ProductId" : null,
         "Name" : null,
         "Description" : null,
         // ... quite a few more properties
         "Properties" : null 
    }
]
```

Since our Product was stored with a discriminator type of "ProductDetail", we'd serialize it into a ProjectItem like this:

```
  BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<ProjectItem>(cm => {
      cm.AutoMap();
      cm.SetDiscriminator("ProductDetails"); // <--- it was stored as a ProductDetails
      cm.SetDiscriminatorIsRequired(true);
  });
```

Comment: Let me know if you need to see more examples. This was a bit confusing to me at first and after I saw enough examples it just clicked